# Does anyone have an original Word 2003 normal.dot file?

Tags: formatting, default-settings, microsoft-word-2003, indentation

I'm running Microsoft Office XP Small Business which has Word 2003.

I need to know what the Original Default settings were in `normal.dot` for Paragraph Formatting, specifically: *Indentation: Special: 1st Line*.

Mine currently reads .5 inches, but I think I may have changed it. I've already gone in and deleted normal.dot, then restarted my computer to (supposedly) reset to the default normal.dot, and it still comes up .5 inches. Is that what it's supposed to be or not?

Somewhere I read that Adobe can prevent this from happening. Don't know if that's true or not, but all I want to know if what the original default is supposed to be.

Does anyone still have an original Word 2003 normal.dot?

Answer (score 1):

The link to the download that's in the page linked in the other answer no longer works.

The original file was, however, [archived by WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100807191102/http://www.vlerick.com:80/helpdesk/our_services/faq/software_solution/microsoft/word/Normal.dot) before it went dark.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://12stix.com/2008/10/29/restoring-normaldot-in-microsoft-office/) has what your looking for.

It has a link to download `normal.dot` and instructions on how to replace it.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I don't want to replace it. I've already tried that and I don't know if it went to original settings or not. I just want to know what it's supposed to be!

Comment: Alas, that link no longer works.  I'd surely like to find one that does.

Comment: @BobBrown It's on WayBackMachine. Check my answer.